# How can I define dynamically the associative array keys?

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have two variable:

```
$keystr = 'plant,fruit,exotic';
$value='kiwi';
```

how can i create the associative array?

```
$arr = ('plant'=>array('fruit'=>array('exotic'=>'kivi')));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$keystr = 'plant,fruit,exotic';
$value='kiwi'; 

$arr = array();
$current = &$arr;
$keys = explode(',', $keystr);
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $current[$key] = array();
    $current = &$current[$key];
}
$current = $value;
unset($current);
var_dump($arr);
```

See http://ideone.com/YiMIRb for a demonstration